# Create Outlook MailItem for each element in an Array?

Tags: c#, arrays, outlook, mailitem

I am trying to create a program which allows users to create an E-Mail draft for several recipients.
The users are allowed to load a .csv file containing the mail-addresses and to choose an attachment.
So far everything works, but the E-Mail is only created for the last element in the array.

I've tried a foreach loop and a basic for loop, but none of it is working.

First I created the objects:

```
var olApplication = new MS.Outlook.Application();
var olMailItem = (MS.Outlook.MailItem)olApplication.CreateItem(MS.Outlook.OlItemType.olMailItem);

var olNamespace = olApplication.GetNamespace("MAPI");
var olUser = olNamespace.CreateRecipient(UserPrincipal.Current.EmailAddress);
var olDrafts = olNamespace.GetSharedDefaultFolder(olUser, MS.Outlook.OlDefaultFolders.olFolderDrafts);
```

Then I used the mailItem inside the loop(s):

```
for (int i = 0; i < recipientArray.Length; i++)
            {
                olMailItem.To = recipientArray[i];
                olMailItem.Subject = tbTitle.Text;
                olMailItem.Body = tbBody.Text;
                if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(attachment))
                {
                    olMailItem.Display(false);
                    olMailItem.Move(olDrafts);
                    break;
                }
                else
                olMailItem.Attachments.Add(attachment);
                olMailItem.Display(false);
                olMailItem.Move(olDrafts);
            }
```

or

```
            foreach (var recipient in recipientArray)
            {
                olMailItem.To = recipient;
                ...
            }
```

Both do the same thing. I thought about creating a new **milItem** everytime in the loop, but I don't know how.

Sorry, I haven't  been programming since school (6 years ago, very basic programs) and I really tried searching the web, but that's as far as I could go.

I tried using a foreach loop (for each recipient in recipientArray) but that doesn't work, it only takes the last element in the Array.
I've also tried using a for loop (comparing i with the length of the recipientArray) but it also only takes the last element.

When filling a textbox with the filled array, it shows all the content.

```
         foreach (string line in File.ReadAllLines(FileDiagAttachment.FileName))
         {
              recipientArray = line.Split('\n');

              foreach (string recipient in recipientArray)
              {
                      tbTest.Text += recipient.ToString() + "\n";
              }
         }
```

I'd gladly appreciate the help.

Comment: Are you trying to create multiple emails for each recipient? Or a single email with all specified recipients?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a recipient in the loop like the following code shows:

```
var olMailItem = (MS.Outlook.MailItem)olApplication.CreateItem(MS.Outlook.OlItemType.olMailItem);
for (int i = 0; i < recipientArray.Length; i++)
{   
    olMailItem.Recipients.Add(recipientArray[i]);
}

// the rest set up 
olMailItem.Subject = tbTitle.Text;
olMailItem.Body = tbBody.Text;
if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(attachment))
{
    olMailItem.Display(false);
    olMailItem.Move(olDrafts);
    break;
}
else
{
   olMailItem.Attachments.Add(attachment);
   olMailItem.Display(false);
   olMailItem.Move(olDrafts);
}
```

The [MailItem.Recipients](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.mailitem.recipients) property returns a `Recipients` collection that represents all the recipients for the Outlook item. Use the `Add` method to create a new Recipient object and add it to the Recipients object. The Type property of a new Recipient object is set to the default for the associated `AppointmentItem`, `JournalItem`, `MailItem`, or `TaskItem` object and must be reset to indicate another recipient type. For example:

```
Set myItem = Application.CreateItem(olMailItem) 
Set myRecipient = myItem.Recipients.Add ("Eugene Astafiev") 
myRecipient.Type = olCC
```

You may find the following articles that I wrote for the technical blog helpful:

- [How To: Create and send an Outlook message programmatically](https://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2011/09/02/outlook-create-send-message/)
- [How To: Fill TO,CC and BCC fields in Outlook programmatically](https://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2011/09/08/outlook-fill-recipients-programmatically/)